# Car vanity lights and front reading lights doesn't work well. What is causing the issue?

Tags: electrical, honda, accord, lights

I have a 2003 Honda Accord. It has reading lights (driver/passenger) right above the review mirror (These are also the lightens that go on when the car door is open).  I also have a vanity mirror with lights under the driver and passenger visor.

The reading lights don't work anymore. I thought it was the bulb but one time the lights went on and then went out.

The vanity lights are spotty. BOTH looked like there was a poor connection.  When I flipped open he mirror he light was dim. I had to tap the light to make it go fully on. Both vanity lights exhibited the same behavior.

Any ideas as to what is causing this?  Is this something that can be solved with new fuses?

**update**
Before the lights went my automatic lock on the driver side doesn't work anymore. 
Also the passenger window sometimes does not go down when I try to "roll down" the window using the window button.

Is my electrical system just getting old? Where does all the wiring go? How do I check?

Comment: From your explanation with the lughts being dim - I would check all connections for corrosion / tightness.

Comment: Thanks! Where would these connections be? Under the hood? What about the fuses?